# Laravel API: Method are confliccting whenever i add the auth:api middleware

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8

I keep having this error whenever my I call my route using a POST request even when my route is really a POST request. And This issue only occurs when I try binding my route with the `auth:api` middleware, please kindly help look into this, and let me know if you will have me provide more information

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in file /home/kingsleyakindele/projects/secpry_backend_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117

here are my routes

```
Route::prefix("auth")->group(function () {
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::post('refresh', [LoginController::class, 'handleRefreshToken'])->name('refresh');
Route::post('me', [LoginController::class, 'userDetails'])->name("user_details");
});
```

this is from my controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware("auth:api", ["except" => ["login", "refresh"]]);
}
```

only the login route works fine, the refresh route and others are not working fine at all.

thanks for your assistance

Comment: Make sure you are calling the route as `post` method on the client side.

Comment: Is there any redirect happening within these routes like e.g. a validation failing redirect?

Comment: @apokryfos, no redirects are going on after validation, I am only returning a  json response

Comment: Validation itself will cause a redirect if it fails unless the request has "Accept: application/json" in the headers

Comment: @apokryfos, thanks that solves it, but now, I am still having the issue that even when I have already logged in, all protected(auth:api) route still returns unauthenticated having passed the auth token and the I am certain the token get's in

Comment: the `auth` middleware will redirect someone to 'login' if they are not authenticated and you don't have a 'login' route that takes GET (which is what the redirect is)

Answer (score 0):

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST.

If you read the error, it says that the get method is not supported.
You have not declared a method get in the routes.

Comment: am I supposed to declare a get method to a route a trigger the route with a post method? I am not sure I got what you meant, kindly explain

Comment: you make a get request and you only have a post

Comment: i made a post request and i have a post also, but the issue is laravel interpreted it as a get request being passed and then return that error